# ActiveX Checkbox blank after copying from another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ms-office, office365, vba

I'm using Office 2016, and when copying a sheet from workbook to workbook, my checkboxes seem to disappear, but really they are still there. The checkboxes only look like they disappear because the rows they reside in are initially hidden. Then once the rows are unhidden, the checkboxes still do not appear.

Using 2007 does not have this effect. If I resize the checkbox it will reappear. Anyone know of any compatibility issues between the versions?  Here's a screen shot:

Suppose to look like:

[image]

After copying sheet to another workbook:

[image]

Comment: Unable to replicate this using Excel 2016. Is there a reason you're using ActiveX controls instead of normal Form controls?

Comment: because i need the checkboxes to hide if the rows it resides on are hidden.

Comment: Noted. Seems to be a bug that has gone unpatched since 2010. See here for some workarounds: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/disappearing-activex-checkboxes-when-hidden-then/0e3fcbed-3156-44f5-a036-4c6cc6f07864?db=5

Comment: curious as to why microsoft has not patched this yet.

Comment: Take it up with microsoft :D